# Add to Login Item - SandBox-friendly solution

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

OK, here's my situation :

- I'm having several apps (Status bar apps, actually), having to start at login (if user wishes so)
- I've been using Uli Kuster's [LoginItem](https://github.com/uliwitness/UliKit) code, which worked flawlessly
- As per latest Apple guidelines, all newly-submitted apps HAVE TO be sandboxed.

The issue :

- `UKLoginItem` and SandBox don't work together. So, I'm looking for an alternative (and acceptable) way to do the very same thing.

Any ideas? Any reference to point me to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an helper tool to start the apps at login.

An example is here:

http://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/

Comment: Thanks a lot! There is no better example that a real-world example. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use the Service Management framework. Specifically, `SMLoginItemSetEnabled`. See [Adding Login Items Using the Service Management Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html).

Note that you *must* use the Service Management framework. The LaunchServices methods are not available in a sandboxed environment.